# Which instance is the best to create an Apollo Graphql microservice on AWS?

Tags: aws-lambda, microservices, apollo, apollo-client, aws-appsync

Looking to create an Apollo Graphql microservice on AWS and am looking for the best way to build this on AWS, AWS do have their own Graphql as a service called Apsync but this seems like a blunt tool. Have found lots of suggestions to use Lambda but not much else. The Graphql layer will resolve data from several other AWS microservices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly don't use AppSync. We used it for a year, and found it's difficult to configure and does not perform well in many types of queries. We ended up using the Apollo Server on top of Lambda. As we use DynamoDb, we wrote our own resolvers (not much effort) as part of using the Apollo Server.

Comment: This sounds awesome, the more I learn about Apollo server the more I'm disliking the sound of Appsync. Thinking of Apollo server on Fargate with the rest of the APIs